# Applying a CodeIgniter page to a WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

Is there any way of doing this? A page was recently built using CI framework - but it now needs to be added to a previously designed site built with WordPress. 
It would be great if we didn't have to scrap what we already have. 
Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dismount the WordPress-codeparts to get a plain HTML-Theme. Then you can apply it to your CodeIgniter script.

Best Regards